# Why (and How Can I FIx) ESLint import/no-extraneous-dependencies Failures on Installed Packages?

Tags: eslint, package.json

When I run ESLint I get the following errors:

```
1:13  error  'joi' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S joi' to add it        import/no-extraneous-dependencies
2:16  error  'lodash' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S lodash' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

However, I have both of those modules installed and in my `package.json`:

```json
"joi": "^10.4.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.2",
```

and running `npm i -S joi` doesn't help or fix the issue. I have tons of other packages in my `package.json`, and only those two have issues.

It's *possible* that this is a bug, but ESLint has so many eyes on it I think it's more likely that I'm doing something wrong, only I can't figure out what (those packages look just the same as any other in my `package.json`).

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing (inadvertently) to make ESLint complaint about those two packages, and only those two packages, despite them being installed?

---

Here's my `package.json` with a few not-relevant identifying bits removed:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "some": "scripts",
  },
  "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit",
    "require": "babel-register",
    "serial": true,
    "verbose": true
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support": "0.0.4",
    "apidoc": "^0.17.5",
    "ava": "^0.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-alias": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-react-render-defender": "^1.1.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.6.1",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "enzyme": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "proxyquire": "^1.7.10",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "really-need": "^1.9.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^1.0.0",
    "s3rver": "^1.0.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "supertest": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.4",
    "ava": "^0.17.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.7.21",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-decorators-legacy": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "celebrate": "^4.0.0",
    "chai-diff": "^1.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clipboard": "^1.6.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "core-decorators": "^0.15.0",
    "csrf": "^3.0.6",
    "css-mqpacker": "^5.0.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.9.1",
    "debug": "^2.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-sanitizer": "^1.0.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "faker": "^3.1.0",
    "feedparser": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "flatpickr": "^2.6.1",
    "helmet": "^3.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.1.1",
    "joi": "^10.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "jsonp-promise": "^0.1.2",
    "knex": "0.12.9",
    "libxmljs": "^0.18.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "node-fetch": "^1.6.3",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "plist": "^2.0.1",
    "postcss": "^5.2.6",
    "postcss-custom-media": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-import": "^9.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dnd": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.3.0",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.10.1",
    "react-modal": "^1.6.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.1",
    "react-virtualized": "^8.11.4",
    "recompose": "^0.23.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-actions": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-debounce": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4",
    "stylelint": "^7.7.0",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.0-beta.2",
    "svgo": "^0.7.1",
    "to-exports": "^0.1.0",
    "twit": "^2.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",,
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0",
    "webpack-split-chunks": "^0.1.1",
    "xmlbuilder": "^8.2.2"
  }
}
```

As you can see it's pretty straightforward; just lots of packages.

---

Here's my `.eslintrc`:

```json
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "NODE_ENV": true,
    "isProduction": true,
    "__ROUTE__": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "babel"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      "error",
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "always-multiline",
        "objects": "always-multiline",
        "imports": "always-multiline",
        "exports": "always-multiline",
        "functions": "ignore"
      }
    ],
    "eol-last": "error",
    "import/order": "error",
    "This next rule is just temporary until we start using PropTypes": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Docker?

Comment: Nope, this is just a plain old Mac environment.  Thanks for taking the time to ask though.

Comment: Did you try to remove your node_modules folder and run npm i?

Comment: Yes; didn't help :(

Comment: Have you tried adding lodash and joi to your DevDependencies?

Comment: Well, Lodash is used by the production code, so it's definitely not a dev dependency. But I tried moving both to the devDependcies, and all that did was add new ` 'lodash' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies` ESLint errors. Interestingly enough though I keep getting 'lodash' should be listed in the project's dependencies errors, but the two are mutually exclusive (any file only has one of those errors, not both)

Comment: I've the same issue and nothing is working. In my case the package in question is `draftjs-utils`, and in trying some solutions below w/o just disabling the rule, I commically get this feedback:
`npm WARN idealTree Removing dependencies.draftjs-utils in favor of devDependencies.draftjs-utils` (so in other words in moving to devDeps highlights that the package IS IN dependencies). I'm on `npm@8.1.2`, `eslint@8.4.1`...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add the following to your eslint, just to have the correct rule in there. And yes you can also turn it off, but the error is there for e reason.

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": false, "optionalDependencies": false, "peerDependencies": false}]
```

As far as I can tell, there is no issue with your package.json, so it has to be a syntax problem.

I don't have your code so I will show the examples:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
import _ from 'lodash';
```

If you have the above code (or something like it)

Then change it to:

```
import test from 'ava';
import find from 'lodash.find';
```

You can read more here:

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even when I added the disabling code (I tried both adding it as a `rules` and as a `settings`) it didn't help.  But obviously I don't want to disable the rule anyway: I just want it to work normally.  As for redoing my imports, that's not really viable (we have *a lot* of Lodash imports, and a fair number of Joi ones too).  Plus, every Joi import we have is identical, and they're all in the format you recommend: `const Joi = require('joi');`.

Comment: I didn't recommend require, I recommended eliminating them. Because a require is seen as an extraneous-dependencies. So I suggested changing it in imports. Also if you use other 3rd party libs a lot, I suggest making a barrel file that gives back all those libs. So you can change out libs much easier, without having to change all your code.

Comment: This is a combined front-end and backend-codebase (Lodash is used by both and Joi is back-end only). While we're using Webpack to get `import` syntax on the front-end we're not on the back-end, so we can only use `require` syntax there.  Regardless, I feel like any solution to fixing some false positives in a linter shouldn't require (no pun intended) changing half the import statements in my codebase.

Comment: Well this is a change to implement it smarter. If you require or import the same stuff in all the time, create a barrel, so you won't have to change every file. It's not a false positive, it does exactly what it supposed to do. I don't quite get the front- backend remark? But if you only want to use require, you should turn the extraneous-dependency rule off.

Comment: re: "I don't quite get the front- backend remark?" We have a web app. Half(-ish) of the code runs on the backend, ie. it serves the APIs which facilitate database access. This code does not use Webpack, but it does use both `lodash` and `joi`. The other half(-ish) of the code powers the front-end: it runs in the user's browser, and is served through Webpack. That code uses `lodash` but not `joi`. As for making a barrel file, that's exactly what `lodash` itself is (Lodash is a library of separate functions in one module): I'm not sure what I'd gain by making a barrel file of a barrel file.

Answer (score 24):

If you arrived here while searching for 'Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found'

Then to fix this issue you should add `"plugins": ["import"]` in your `.eslintrc` file

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the least invasive solution

Comment: No idea _why_ this works, but it works, without touching anything else. Note that I had already set `devDependencies: true` on a previous go-round with this rule, which seemed to work at the time, but it was no longer solving the problem.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem.

What solved it for me was to add a packageDir option explicitly:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
    "error", {
       "devDependencies": false, 
       "optionalDependencies": false, 
       "peerDependencies": false, 
       "packageDir": "./"
    }
]
```

Comment: I had to use `"packageDir": __dirname` instead to make it work in VS Code. Source: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md

Comment: Thanks @SillyFreak, that's actually what solved my problem. Care to make it an answer? Probably more vscode folks here …

Comment: The `packageDir: __dirname` solution worked, though I had to change the file type from `.eslintrc` to `.eslintrc.js` to get the `__dirname`.

Answer (score 16):

I solved it simply by setting devDependencies to true. By default it is false.

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
        "error", {
           "devDependencies": true
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Docs say it defaults to `true`, perhaps it changed recently. https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md#options

Comment: nice @DaryaWiśniewski

Answer (score 10):

`devDependencies: packageDir` or `devDependencies: false` solutions above didn't work for me, but eventually I solved this. Here's what worked for me:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
  "error",
  {
    "devDependencies": ["test/**"],
    "optionalDependencies": false,
    "peerDependencies": false
  }
],
```

Just list your tests folder in `devDependencies` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by simply deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` then doing a fresh `npm install`

Answer (score 6):

For me, I finally figured out that the linter error was **not** happening when I ran `yarn lint` in the console and it was only VSCode that was erroneously highlighting my import statements with this error. Closing the project and re-opening in VSCode fixed the issue.

Comment: Jesus this was also my issue. tried everything EXCEPT restarting VSCode

Comment: You can also run `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server` from the command palette, which will often solve issues related to changed paths, etc.

Comment: Oddly, I've also experienced the opposite problem: VSCode is fine once I restart it, but every time I run a build from Terminal, it throws. Setting `"plugins": ["import"]` magically fixed that for me.

Answer (score 5):

What I did to fix this:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
  "error",
  {
    "devDependencies": [
      "**/*.stories.*",
      "**/.storybook/**/*.*",
      "**/*.test.*"
    ],
    "peerDependencies": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I have faced similar issues and resolved them differently to everyone else here so  far. I am using TypeScript and while my setup works with most packages every now and then there is a package which throws that `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` error.

The key part of my .eslintrc:

```
  "settings": {
    "import/core-modules": ["dayjs"]
  }
```

Dayjs was one of the modules giving me this error, but you can add any module giving you the error into the core-modules array and it resolves the issue.

Comment: Cheers mate, after trying all the above, yours were the right one for me.

Comment: worked for me with nanoid as well: 

  "settings": {
    "import/core-modules": ["nanoid"]
  }

But I removed the "typescript": {} because it breaks other things

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, because some tool (most probably "rollup") generated another `package.json` (containing empty JSON `{}`) in my project's subdirectory. Deleting that file helped.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when use yarn, I had same problem:

To solve, I run following commands:

```
yarn cache clean
rm -rf yarn.lock
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I was working on a project which had another package.json file nested in a child directory. This error was occurring on all files within or children of that second directory.

SOLUTION: make a copy eslintrc file in the child directory containing the other package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

The project I found this issue on uses a mix of imports and require() for importing files/packages.  I resolved this issue by adding commonjs to the env config

```
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to import a package that begins with an "@" for example "@aws-sdk/client-sqs" what worked for me is adding single quotes around the double quotes per [documentation](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.29.1/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md#pass) `import {SQSClient} from '"@aws-sdk/client-sqs"';`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem occurred during an Angular upgrade.

Compiling my library worked, but the linter threw errors when importing from my library: **import/no-extraneous-dependencies**.

What eventually fixed it, was upgrading **@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin** and **@typescript-eslint/parser**.

The Angular upgrade updated my **typescript** version, which was no longer compatible with these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'usePackageJson' property to fix it, like this:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
  "error",
  {
    "devDependencies": false,
    "optionalDependencies": false,
    "peerDependencies": false,
    "usePackageJson": true
  }
]
```

I was having similar issues with the morgan package. This fixed it for me.