# 'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I ran `npm install prop-types --save-dev`
and started getting this error

`'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies  import/no-extraneous-dependencies`

Later I uninstalled the dependency by running `npm uninstall prop-types --save-dev` and installed again by running `npm install prop-types --save`

Still the error doesn't go

`'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S prop-types' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies`

Comment: Go to your package.json, and move prop-types from devDependencies to dependencies

Comment: Save to the regular dependencies, not the dev ones.

Comment: still doesn't work after relaunching the console

Comment: —save-dev saves to dev dependencies, just use —save or avoid that flag entirely as —save is default behavior

Comment: Better answer is to just edit the lint rule. `prop-types` is a dev dependency, not a real dependency. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989739/why-and-how-can-i-fix-eslint-import-no-extraneous-dependencies-failures-on-ins

Answer (score 9):

Your package.json probably currently looks something like

```
{
  "name": "your-website",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    ...

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.18",
    ...
  },
}
```

Make it look like

```
{
  "name": "your-website",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    ...

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.18",
    ...
  },
}
```

by moving prop-types from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`

After this, run `npm install` or `yarn install` if you are using yarn

---

Your devDependencies are the ones that are used while building your project. They are not present in the production of your project. When someone opens a website in a browser the code for the devDependencies is not in it

---

When you install a package

- using `npm install` will put the package into your `package.json` as a `dependency`
- using `npm install --save-dev` will put the package in your
  `package.json` as a `devDependency`

Comment: even after moving from dev-deps to dependencies error persists

Comment: @RahulYadav and you ran `npm install`?

Comment: @RahulYadav You could try deleting your node_modules folder after, or running `npm clean`, and that's my whole bag of tricks

Comment: @RahulYadav thank you, deleting node_modules and running `npm install` after helped me

Answer (score 2):

You should execute this command:
`rm -rfd ./node_modules`
to delete node_modules directory and then change your package.json manually  like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "prop-types": <YOUR_VERSION>,
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
```

and finally, run `npm i` or `yarn` if you're using yarn.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what helped me;
I think I had hit an npm bug and so I ran "npm install prop-types", then removed the node_modules and package-lock.json;
and ran npm install afresh. Worked well after that!