# React component not importing dependencies that have been installed and listed in package.json and package-lock.json

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, components, package.json, importerror

In a React component file I have imported the following two dependencies:

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

`import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';`

Both of these are have been installed using the npm install command, and appear in the package.json as well as the package-lock.json files, thus:

`"dependencies": {`

```
"prop-types": "^15.8.1",

"react": "^18.2.0",

"react-dom": "^18.2.0",

"react-hook-form": "^7.43.0,`
```

... etc

In spite of which I obtain the messages:

`'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies`

`'react-hook-form' should be listed in the project's dependencies`

I have tried deleting the node_modules and the package-lock.json files and then running `npm install` several times, but it does not resolve the issue.

What can I do to get the component to successfully import these dependencies and resolve the issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866065/prop-types-should-be-listed-in-the-projects-dependencies-not-devdependencies)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, both 'prop-types' and 'react-hook-form' are already listed in my project's dependencies and not in devDependencies.

Comment: Solved the Issue! All it required was to use the command `yarn install` instead of `npm install` after having deleted `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Comment: @German how are you installing after having deleted package.json? did you mean node_modules and package-lock.json?

Comment: You're right, @S.Alvi. I will edit the question so as to not misguide any newbies (like myself) that might read it.